# How do the nl80211 library & cfg80211 work?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, wifi

I want to learn about how `nl80211` and `cfg80211` work in detail, such as: function flow and how `nl80211` interacts with network tools like `wpa_supplicant` and `iw`.

Comment: This question is off-topic. See [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 71):

To be able to control wireless drivers from userspace, some IPC communication processes between kernel and userspace are used.

- At first `ioctl` with vendor dependent APIs was used.
- In 1996, Jean Tourrilhes creates [wireless extensions](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html) (WE or WEXT).

> The Wireless Extension (WE) is a generic API allowing a driver to
>   expose to the user space configuration and statistics specific to
>   common Wireless LANs.

- In 2006, John Linville creates [mac80211](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/mac80211) and Johannes Berg creates [cfg80211](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/cfg80211) and [nl80211](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/nl80211). Together it is intended to replace wireless extensions.

  ```
  +-------------+
  |             |
  |  Userspace  |
  |             |
  +-------------+
        ^
  - - - | - - - - 
        | nl80211
        v
  +-------------+
  |             |
  |  cfg80211   |
  |             |
  +-------------+
  +-------------+
  |             |
  |  mac80211   |
  |   driver    |
  |             |
  +-------------+
  ```

An important point is that nl80211/cfg80211/mac80211 no longer use ioctl, they use [netlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink).

So, tools like [iw](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw), [hostapd](http://hostap.epitest.fi/hostapd/) or the [wpa_supplicant](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/) use some netlink libraries (like [libnl](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/) or [libnl-tiny](http://git.openwrt.org/?p=openwrt.git;a=tree;f=package/libs/libnl-tiny)) and the netlink interface public header which is of course [nl80211.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/nl80211.h).

There is not so much documentations, but I advise you to read the [libnl documentation](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/) and then the [iw source code](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/jberg/iw.git) (because iw use libnl).

Comment: nl80211 act as an interface between userspace and kernel space.....i m having difficulty in understanding at what point control flow goes from user space to kernel space

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/doc/core.html#core_netlink_fundamentals). Netlink can be compared to a socket between the kernel and the user space. So the user can use it in a request-response way (e.g `iw dev wlan0 link`) and/or in an event way (e.g `iw dev wlan0 event`).

Comment: thanks for the link but i have gone through that page.....for interaction between user n kernel space a socket is created...but when it comes to tracing the code i m not able to trace it from user space to kernel space....if anybody can help plz reply soon

Comment: You can search in the [linux-wireless mailing list](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/MailingLists) or even try asking them. If you got a response, please post it, I'm very interested in and I don't have enough time to do it now!

Comment: ^ Link is dead, here's an archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20160316163624/http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/doc/core.html

Answer (score 45):

A slightly more detailed picture of how `nl80211` and `cfg80211` work with other parts of the system (`user space`, `kernel`, and `hardware`).

- `nl80211` is the interface between user space software (`iw`, `wpa_supplicant`, etc.) and the kernel (`cfg80211` and `mac80211` kernel modules, and specific drivers).
- The WiFi drivers and hardware could be Full-MAC or Soft-MAC (see [Wireless_network_interface_controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_network_interface_controller)).
- `cfg80211_ops` is a set of operations that Full-MAC drivers and `mac80211` module register to `cfg80211` module.
- `ieee80211_ops` is a set of operations that Soft-MAC drivers register to `mac80211` module.

[image]

Comment: lspci -k | grep -A 3 -i "network" returns me "Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi". Then modinfo iwlwifi | grep depends returns me "cfg80211". But how can I check about nl80211 and mac80211. Also, how do I know if the driver supports AP mode or not?

Answer (score 11):

I've created a basic code flow diagram for the wireless stack in linux,
all the way from wpa_supplicant > cfg80211 > mac80211 > ath9k_htc.

The code has been traced for linux kernel 5.4.31.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/akshdeep-singh/80211_code_flow_linux/blob/master/codeflow.pdf).

Comment: Wow, it is awesome.
 Which software did you use to create this diagram?

Comment: @ItachiTensie I didn't use any software, I just made it with Google Drawings...

Answer (score 9):

See my reply to 
[How to learn the structure of Linux wireless drivers (mac80211)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157181/how-to-learn-the-structure-of-wireless-drivers-mac80211/18026691#18026691)

In `wpa_supplicant`, you can follow the code in `src/drivers/driver_nl80211.c`. This is a wpa_supplicant driver (not a kernel driver but an abstraction used in `wpa_supplicant` code) which uses `libnl` to communicate with the kernel `cfg80211` module. When `wpa_supplicant` issues a scan for example then `wpa_driver_nl80211_scan` gets called. It builds the `netlink` message with a command called `NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN` and with all the parameters required for the scan.