# RCPI and RSNI of wifi network using C program

Tags: wifi, linux-device-driver

Can anyone tell me how to find WiFi RCPI (Received channel power indication) and RSNI (Received signal to noise indicator) and load of a given wifi network using C program in ubuntu?? Else can you suggest me how to write such programs ??

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, the wifi stack is compose of a **linux device driver** and a userspace daemon which is **[wpa_supplicant](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant)**. The **wpa_supplicant** talks directly to the wifi driver which can be various kinds (mostly 2: [the new 80211 drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456235/how-nl80211-cfg80211-libraries-work) or [the old wext](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/Wireless-Extensions)).

So you can check the [`wpa_cli`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_cli) command to get wifi status. Or talks directly to the **wpa_supplicant** with his [control interface](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html).

If you don't care about the *wpa_supplicant* and you want to talk directly to the driver. Check the [Linux wireless site](http://wireless.kernel.org) to get more informations about the different driver types.

Comment: Any updates now 6-9 years later?